# macports repair/replace command?

Tags: macports

I accidentally removed /opt/local/bin/perl5.8.9 , which seems to be the main binary file for perl compiled by macports.

Now I have a lots of ports depending on perl5, but don't want to uninstall and reinstall all of them.

Is there a way to repair or reinstall and replace a port? 
Or is /opt/local/bin/xx only a symlink? If so, where is the original binary?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
$ port -f uninstall perl5.8    # Force removal of perl5.8
$ port install perl5.8         # Install it again
```